# Firefox cache path construction Mac OS X

Tags: java, firefox, caching, macos

I know the path for Firefox's cache is as follows on Mac OS X Leopard:

~/Library/Caches/Firefox/Profiles/COMPUTER_CODE.default/Cache

How is the variable "COMPUTER_CODE" above created? I assume it is different from computer to computer. I want to be able to programmatically delete this cache if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is randomly generated.  The code that generates it [can be found here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/profile/src/nsToolkitProfileService.cpp#613).